Can LIGO or some other experiment confirm the radius-mass relation of black holes?
For Schwarzschild black holes, mass and radius are proportional. Physics is an experimental science. Could LIGO or some other measurement system confirm this?
Can both quantities be measured separately? Graphs of black hole masses are everywhere, especially from LIGO. Can LIGO also measure radii?
I am really curious, and did not find any reference via Google Scholar. It might be that this is too obvious. Does anybody know about any experimental check of the mass-radius relation?

“For Schwarzschild black holes, mass and radius are proportional.” - Not if by radius you mean the spacelike radial distance from the horizon to the origin, which is zero in remote coordinates for any black hole. Also Schwarzschild and Kerr black holes don’t exist and cannot be measured.

Well, of course, the "usual" radius R = GM/c^2 was implied. And Schwarzschild and Kerr black holes are a good approximation to observations.

LIGO can’t measure static gravitational fields. It’s an interferometer; it can detect the extremely-minute variations in spacetime due to gravitational waves (emitted by dynamic or non-static gravitational fields) with high efficacy, but if the black hole is just sitting there (as opposed to orbiting/merging with another black hole), LIGO and LISA are just glorified sets of tubes. You might be thinking of the Event Horizon Telescope (EHT), which can directly image black holes with a lot of effort.
When black holes do collide, they emit extremely powerful gravitational radiation. LIGO and other interferometer can directly detect this, and by knowing the energy of the gravitational wave emitted and the approximate distance (both of which we can identify with relative ease, compared to directly observing black holes’ properties), we can know how big the black holes were before they merged, and thus the final mass as well. Their radius is instead confirmed by things like the EHT and the distance from their centers at which we note that their accretion disks redshift out of existence.
Taking pictures of and identifying the precise radius of black holes is extremely difficult. We can’t go there to check ourselves$^\text{citation needed}$, so the best we can do is observer orbiting objects and accretion disks. In general we’ve found Schwarzschild’s original calculations to hold mostly true, although many black holes we find (like Sagittarius A*, that really big one at the center of the Milky Way) are rotating at least somewhat, making the Kerr metric more accurate.
It’s not that we can’t know anything about black holes, but they’re pretty difficult to view through telescopes of any kind to directly estimate their radii/masses. But what we can note it how objects orbit around it, and they do so in very predictable ways. The Kerr and Schwarzschild metrics are exceedingly good at predicting these orbits.
The graphs of black hole masses/radii are probably calculating the radii from the masses, which are more easily known. For all intents and purposes, we can confirm that mass and radius are proportional, the constant of proportionality being $\frac{2G}{c^2}$.

"LIGO can’t measure anything that doesn’t emit gravitational waves." -- I know what you mean, but this might be a little misleading because LIGO does measure tons of things that aren't gravitational waves (which are then classified as noise). Like, vibrations in the Earth, magnetic fields from stray currents, thermal motion in the system, thirsty ravens... and even fluctuations in the Newtonian gravitational fields due to sesimic waves in the Earth (a noise source which will affect future interferometers).

Maybe, "LIGO cannot detect static gravitational fields" would be better?

That is a good point. By “measure” I was referring to the thing that it is designed to measure; it can also detect many other things. Thanks for that!

Just as a comment: the text does not answer the question ...

What I tried to say in my question: LIGO cannot directly observe black hole masses/radii, although the relationship between mass and radius has been otherwise confirmed.

A reference would be welcome!

You can read about what it does and how it works on LIGO’s webpage. By definition interferometers cannot effectively measure static gravitational fields, especially at such great range.
